# Convert 4-byte hex into decimal value

Tags: c#

I've got a piece of hardware that requires a certain parameter to be set in order to function properly. I'll be sending the value to the device using C#. The device only accepts a single decimal value; however, the values I'm being told to input are given to me as 4-byte HEX numbers. I understand how to convert a single hex to a decimal, but I'm not sure how to convert 4 bytes.

The hex values I'm given are these: `0x00, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x03`. What steps do I take to convert that to a single decimal value? For extra credit, if I were using the Windows calc in "Programmer Mode" would there be a way to figure it out (I'm also trying to understand the concepts required to do this)?

As an FYI, the hardware describes this parameter in the following way:

```
Size    4   
Default 8

Name    Report type send in Reporting Group 1 - Defines the type of report sent for the Reporting Group 1.

Type    rangemapped

Values  
1     ->    Battery Report
2     ->    MultiSensor Report for the whole device
4     ->    Meter Report for Watt for the whole device
8     ->    Meter Report for kWh for the whole device
256   ->    Meter Report for Watt for clamp 1
512   ->    Meter Report for Watt for clamp 2
1024      ->    Meter Report for Watt for clamp 3
2048      ->    Meter Report for kWh for clamp 1
4096      ->    Meter Report for Watt for clamp 2
8192      ->    Meter Report for kWh for clamp 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BitConverter class for this

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first), 
// reverse the byte array. 
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx

You will need to know whether the hex numbers themselves are [Little Endian or Big Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  If your current system architecture (indicated by BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) does not match the endianness of the sequence of hex numbers, you will need the call to Array.Reverse as shown in the example (the example assumes the bytes are big endian).

**Extra Credit**

The four numbers represent four "base 256" values (same as base 0x100 values).  Assuming the numbers are big endian, you can do the calculation yourself like:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x03 =>

0x0 * 256^3 + 0x0 * 256^2 + 0x1b * 256^1 + 0x03 * 256 ^ 0 =
0 * 16777216 + 0 * 65536 + 27 * 256 + 3 * 1 =
6915
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please advice how to convert decimal to 4 byte hex like                   
00 00 00 00 = decimal( 0 )
01 00 00 00 = decimal( 1 )
02 00 00 00 = decimal( 2 )
 
0A 00 00 00 = decimal( 10 )
 
FF 00 00 00 = decimal( 255 )
00 01 00 00 = decimal( 256 )
01 01 00 00 = decimal( 257 )
02 01 00 00 = decimal( 258 )

Comment: Please ask this in the form of a new question.  You will have to specify whether you want a big-endian or little-endian representation in your question.